# NSURL Bookmarks: A Faster Alternative?

Tags: objective-c, macos, performance, cocoa, nsurl

### Context

My app's model is a tree of objects where each object represents a filesystem item (a folder or file) on disk beneath a given starting folder.

Periodically, I recursively walk this tree from top-down in order to "sync" it to the actual state of the filesystem. That is, I visit each object in the model and verify that the file/folder it represents still exists in the same location on disk.

If the file/folder has moved, I use an `NSURL` bookmark to ascertain the new location of the file/folder so that I can update my model's state. (I create an `NSURL` bookmark when I first create the model object and then store the bookmark data as a property of the object so that I can resolve it later.)

---

### The Problem

`NSURL` bookmarks simply aren't performant enough. It's not uncommon for my model graph to have 20,000 nested objects. Each one has a bookmark. Here's what I'm seeing when I profile performance:

[image]

The `recursivelyValidateExistingChildItemsOfParentItem:...` method is what walks my model tree. 90% of the time involved is just resolving bookmarks (and, if they are stale, re-creating them as described in Apple's documentation).

The app takes almost 2 minutes to complete the walk thanks to this. So, I need a faster alternative to `NSURL` bookmarks.

---

### What I've Considered

1. Extended File Attributes. I could add a UUID attribute to each file on disk. Instead of walking my model graph, I could walk the actual filesystem underneath the starting folder. When I find a new file, I could see if it has a UUID extended attribute. If so, I could then search my model graph for the object with that UUID to handle moved/relocated files. The trouble here is that many things clobber extended file attributes—they aren't guaranteed to stick around.
2. `BDAlias` or `NDAlias`. I used to use `BDAlias` before I migrated to `NSURL` bookmarks, but that wasn't exceptionally more performant.

---

### Bottom Line

I need a faster alternative to `NSURL`'s bookmarks. But I still need to be able to track files across launches of my app, so simply keeping file descriptors open or using file id's won't work.

I don't care how low-level I have to get; I just need performance. Thanks!

Comment: *Periodically, I recursively walk this tree from top-down in order to "sync" it to the actual state of the filesystem.* This, not the performance of NSURL bookmarks, is probably a good chunk of your problem. You may not be able to avoid validating a large directory structure on each launch, but thereafter you shouldn't need to scan the whole thing—instead, use the [FSEvents API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) to be notified of filesystem changes so you can scan only what you need to, when you need to.

Comment: Thanks Rickster. You can assume that FSEvents and I are *intimately* acquainted. I've extremely familiar with every aspect of that API. It's great for learning, "stuff in folder X has changed". It's not great for knowing where the stuff that used to be in X has gone---which is precisely the problem I need to solve. Even in file-level granularity mode, FSEvents is not the appropriate solution. And, as you pointed out, it does not help across launches.

Comment: Also: I didn't mean to be dismissive. There are just very good reasons that require my full-scan approach. FSEvents can drop events, the user may change the file system when FSEvents is not tracking (like on a removable USB key on another Mac), some folders are actually remote servers mounted via MacFuse, which doesn't handle events the same, etc. I kept this stuff out for brevity. I wish I didn't have to do a full scan, but it's the only reliable way to handle ALL the edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old. But this is my answer:

I only use resolving bookmark as a fallback. I save both file path and URL bookmark data in my model. When I want to open file, first I check if the file still exists in the previously known location. If not, I would try to resolve url's bookmark data. This would narrow calling to `URL.init(resolvingBookmarkData)` only to a limited subset of items. I would then update model with new path after resolving bookmark to keep performance reasonable.

If you need to assure you are working with exactly the same file, you can check file's date, size or a specific EA as an extra measurement.